# Oracle APEX Interactive report filter error

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-19.1

I have created 3 Oracle SQL tables with primary and foreign keys as specified in brackets below:

1. Application (PK: app_id)
2. Vendor (PK: vendor_id, FK :app_id referencing Application table)
3. Servers (PK: server_id, FK :app_id referencing Application table)

My requirement is that when I click on a single application record in the report, it should open all the servers and vendors associated with it on a new page.

In the application page, I have added a new column in SQL query and set the link to redirect to server page. I have added a hidden field(P5_NEW) in the server page and tried writing the below SQL query. Should I modify the query?

```
select application.application_id,SERVER_ID,
       APP_ID,
       etc...
  from SERVER, APPLICATION
where server.app_id=application.application_id and
  APPLICATION.APPLICATION_ID = :P5_NEW;
```

Also, please note that I have created an interactive report which displays all server records when the server is selected on the left menu on the home page.

I am not getting the correct output/records with the method I'm trying.
Please let me know if further info/clarification is required. Thanks in advance and your help is much appreciated.

[server page designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnvGw.png)

[application page designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEuhB.png)

[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faKZ9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first screenshot ("server page designer"), you're missing the **Page items to submit** property. Put `P5_NEW` in there. Otherwise, query doesn't know its value and returns invalid data.

Comment: I did that but not getting any data. The page says "No data found.". Am I missing anything else?

Comment: Looks like WHERE clause isn't working as expected. Can't tell why. If possible, create an example on apex.oracle.com and provide login credentials so that someone could have a look.

Comment: Okay I will do that. Meanwhile, can you please let me know if I need to change anything under source for P5_NEW. (https://ibb.co/NCx5sjR)

Comment: Sorry, I can't see that image - proxy won't let me.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I cross verified and the output was as expected.